# Unable to Start VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to start my Vscode today . I tried re-installing it but while starting it bounces for 2 seconds and stops .
I tried `code --verbose`. It gave me following output. :

`[main 2019-06-10T07:29:13.387Z] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/Users/macos/.vscode'
[main 2019-06-10T07:29:13.389Z] Lifecycle#kill()`

I have tried re-installing but doenot seems to work. Then I tried previous versions to install but it failed to.

Comment: does `/Users/macos` exist? Did you try to add `.vscode` by hand using `mkdir .vscode`?

Comment: I have folder within /Users/macos/ but if run `mkdir .vscode` in terminal . It says.   `mkdir .vscode
mkdir: .: No such file or directory`

Comment: can you try mkdir while using quotation marks around the folder name?

Comment: `macos$ sudo mkdir "/Users/macos/.vscode/"`
`mkdir: /Users/macos: No such file or directory` Its not working

Comment: And I assume correct your os is `macos`? what does `ls -l /Users` show?

Comment: `drwxrwxrwt   7 root   wheel   224 Mar 29 17:02 Shared` 

`drwxr-xr-x+ 49 macos  staff  1568 Jun 10 14:05 macos`